# How to do custom onDraw that draws into space of other components

Tags: java, android

I need to connect visualy components in my aplication. I use custom Button as a node and it has connections. I try to draw a line between connected buttons like this.

[image]

But so far i have something like this. It seems line does not want to be drawn outside of button space.

[image]

Here is my onDraw function.

```
    @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    for(int i = 0; i < connections.size(); i++)
    {
        Paint clr = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        clr.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        clr.setStrokeWidth(5);
        canvas.drawLine(this.getX(), this.getY(), connections.get(i).getX(), connections.get(i).getY(), clr);
    }
}
```

And here is how i create buttons.

```
  rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.designer_section1_solution, container, false);

                for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                    final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.designer_layout);
                    ciButton btn = items.get(i);
                    btn.setTextSize(14);
                    btn.setX(50 + (i % 2) * 500);
                    btn.setY(50 + (i / 2) * 250);
                    View.OnTouchListener action = new MultiTouchListener(layout);
                    btn.setOnTouchListener(action);
                    layout.addView(btn, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }
                ciButton btn = items.get(0);
                btn.connections.add(items.get(1));
```

designer_connection1_solution.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/designer_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is it even possible to do it this way? I have no experience in drawing on android and don't know ho to make this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make a view to perform draw out of its bounds. But you can create custom layout that extends `RelativeLayout` and override its `onDraw()` method--there you should perform drawing of all connectors. So your `onDraw()` method, which looks quite correct, should override not `Button`'s onDraw, but your custom layout's onDraw.

And don't forget to invoke your custom layout's `invalidate()` method each time positions of buttons are changed or connectors are added/deleted. This will force its redraw.